# Add a confirmation dialog box for COD payment in WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-method

I'm using the following code on the checkout page to confirm the Cash on Delivery and proceed with the order, but even if the order is getting confirmed even if the visitor has not clicked on 'Confirm' button.

```
// Popup Confirmation
function add_cod_confirmation_popup() {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) {
        return;
    }

    $selected_payment_method_id = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
    // print_r( $selected_payment_method_id );
    if ("cod" === $selected_payment_method_id){
          // Replace 'cod' with the appropriate payment method ID for Cash on Delivery
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cod_confirmation_popup_script' );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cod_confirmation_popup_style' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp', 'add_cod_confirmation_popup' );
function cod_confirmation_popup_script() {
  ?>
  <script>
    // Get the billing phone field
    var billingPhone = document.getElementById("billing_phone");
    // Validate
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('form.checkout').on('submit', function(e) {
          var $form = $(this);
          var confirmInput = '<input type="hidden" name="confirm_cod" value="1">';

          if ($('.confirmation-modal').length === 0) {
              e.preventDefault();

              var confirmationModal = '<div class="confirmation-modal">' +
                  '<div class="modal-content">' +
                  '<p>Are you sure you want to place the order with Cash on Delivery?</p>' +
                  '<button class="confirm-button">Confirm</button>' +
                  '<button class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '</div>';

              $('body').append(confirmationModal);

              $('.confirm-button').on('click', function() {
                  $('.confirmation-modal').remove();
                  $form.append(confirmInput);
                  $form.submit();
              });

              $('.cancel-button').on('click', function() {
                  location.reload(true);
              });
          }
      });
  });      
  </script>
  <?php
}

function cod_confirmation_popup_style() {
  ?>
  <style>
      .confirmation-modal {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          z-index: 9999;
      }

      .modal-content {
          background-color: #fff;
          padding: 20px;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
  </style>
  <?php
}
```

I've tried adding a reload button on cancel but it is still taking time.

I expect to keep the popup on the screen until it is confirmed.

--

Update:

Added the codes but the "Cancel button" is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have revisited your jQuery code, removed the unnecessary 1st PHP function and changed the hook for the last function.

Now when accessing checkout, if Cod payment is the chosen method by default or when Cod payment is selected by the customer, the confirmation dialog box appear and the hidden input field is added to checkout form:

- If the "confirm" button is ticked, "1" is set as value in the hidden input field, and the confirmation dialog box disappear.
- If the "cancel" button is ticked, "o" is set as value in the hidden input field, and the confirmation dialog box disappear.

If after the customer select another payment method, the hidden input field is removed.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cod_confirmation_popup_script' );
function cod_confirmation_popup_script() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var billingPhone    = $("#billing_phone").val(), // ??? Not used (can be removed)
            paymentSel      = 'input[name="payment_method"]',
            confirmInput    = '<input type="hidden" name="confirm_cod" value="1">',
            inputConfirmSel = 'input[name="confirm_cod"]';

        function loadCodModal() {
            if ($('.confirmation-modal').length === 0 ) {
                var chosenPayment   = $(paymentSel+':checked').val(),
                    confirmationModal   = '<div class="confirmation-modal">' +
                    '<div class="modal-content">' +
                    '<p>Are you sure you want to place the order with Cash on Delivery?</p>' +
                    '<button class="confirm-button">Confirm</button>' +
                    '<button class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

                if ( chosenPayment === 'cod' ) {
                    $('body').append(confirmationModal);
                    $('form.checkout').append(confirmInput);

                    $('.confirm-button').on('click', function() {
                        $('.confirmation-modal').remove();
                        $(inputConfirmSel).val('1');
                    });

                    $('.cancel-button').on('click', function() {
                        $('.confirmation-modal').remove();
                        $(inputConfirmSel).val('0');
                    });
                }  else {

                }
            }
        };
        // On load (on start)
        loadCodModal();

        // On payment method change
        $('form.checkout').on('change', paymentSel, function() {
            chosenPayment = $(this).val();
            
            if( chosenPayment === 'cod' ) {
                loadCodModal();
            } else if ($(inputConfirmSel).length !== 0 ) {
                $(inputConfirmSel).remove();
            }
            // Update checkout on payment method change
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });      
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'cod_confirmation_popup_style' );
function cod_confirmation_popup_style() {
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <style>
      .confirmation-modal {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          z-index: 9999;
      }

      .modal-content {
          background-color: #fff;
          padding: 20px;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
    </style>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but there's still an issue, if someone is clicking on Cancel, the payment method should not change.

Comment: yeh I totally understand that, but it is still selecting Cash on Delivery even if you press the cancel button, please have a look at the codes, it only removes the modal that's all.

Comment: is there any way, I can trigger the model when clicked on Place Order?

Comment: That is not what you asked in your initial question… My actual updated code works perfectly now, so as this answer works and answer your **initial question**, could you please accept this answer (To mark an answer as accepted,
 click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in), thank you. Now to "trigger the model when clicked on Place Order" you should ask a new question.

Comment: The code is for that only, I asked for the same. I'm really sorry for any misunderstanding.